# Should a link as part of a custom close reason be included in the "Linked" questions?

Tags: feature-request, linked-questions, custom-close-reasons

For example, [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/24039/learn-to-read-online-resources) at Chinese.SE has the custom close reason:

> [image]

It links to [Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese), but the link doesn't appear in the "Linked" list:

> [image]

I'm not sure if this is intentional or not, so...

**Question**: Should a link as part of a custom close reason be included in the "Linked" questions?

Answer (score 7):

That's a surprisingly good idea, especially since that link isn't visible to everyone anymore (ever since the UI overhaul on those banners):

> [image: Screenshot of the same question, but without the link]

For maximum effect you'd want that link visible for everyone, including the lower-reputation users.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t think of that. Good point!